# Correct way to catch fetch errors in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple react component that looks like this:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/some-url-here')
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('failed to fetch');
      });
  }

  render() {
    // render the data here
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that the `catch` doesn't just catch fetch errors. It also catches any exceptions thrown in `render` ! What would be the correct way to create a simple component that fetches some data and handles fetch errors?

Comment: If you pull the fetch out into its own function and then call it in componentDidMount, does it still catch the render errors?

Comment: Just tried it, it still catches them

Comment: If you use the `.then` second callback instead of the `.catch` ? [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: I would recommend trying to resolve the errors in your render before trying to debug this. If it can't render, it won't correctly mount, right?

Comment: @GabrielBleu interesting that works, wonder if this is the ideal way of doing thing in react

Comment: @webdevdani yes definitely, this is just an example, it's possible that there will be exceptions in `render` in the future, and I don't want that to be caught

Comment: @GabrielBleu Ahh, its because the setState is causing a render so when that happens and there's an error, it gets passed on to the catch!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/some-url-here')
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data });
      }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          // handle error here
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    // render the data here
  }
}
```

If you use a catch instead of second callback, any errors that might've occurred during setState method would be left unhandled. So you can capture render method errors in your own way.
For more info, give a reading on this tweet by Dan Abramov.

[Dan's Tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/770914221638942720?lang=en)

Comment: actually, I think you mean to pass the error callback to `.then`? Not `error` inside the first callback of `then` ?

Comment: @Vic Yep! Corrected my code. Thanks for the warning